# Evaluate $\int_{-7}^9\frac{-4}{x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

5.4

Can somebody verify this solution for me?? Thanks!!

Evaluate $\int_{-7}^9\frac{-4}{x}dx$

---

$\int_{-7}^9\frac{-4}{x}dx$

$=-4\int_{-7}^9\frac{1}{x}dx$

$=-4ln(|x|)|_{-7}^9dx$

$=-4(ln(|9|)-ln(|-7|))$

$=-4(ln(9)-ln(7))$

$=-4ln(\frac{9}{7})$

Comment: Not correct. Hint: What about $x=0$?

Comment: @HansLundmark: It's almost correct. It would be correct if the question were "Evaluate the [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) of..."

Comment: are you sure the function you're integrating is continuous over the interval you're integrating in?

Comment: @sai-kartik: An integrable function doesn't have to be continuous!

Comment: This function is not integrable over $[-7, 9]$ without doing something like what @TonyK has suggested (i.e. requires a regularization).

Comment: @TonyK what i mean to say is that the given function isn't continuous in the defined limits and the [fundamental principle of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Corollary) cannot be applied

Comment: @sai-kartik: yes, that does make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $-\frac{4}{x}$ has a singularity near $x = 0$. You have to deal with it somehow, e.g.

$$
\begin{aligned}
-\text{P.V.}\int_{-7}^9\frac{4}{x}dx &= \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\left(-4\left(\int_{-7}^{-\varepsilon}\frac{1}{x}dx + \int_{+\varepsilon}^9\frac{1}{x}dx\right)\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 3):

$\int^9_{-7}{\frac{-4}{x}dx}=\int^0_{-7}{\frac{-4}{x}dx}+\int^9_{0}{\frac{-4}{x}dx} = \lim_{a \rightarrow 0^-}\int^a_{-7}{\frac{-4}{x}dx} + lim_{b \rightarrow 0^+}\int^9_{b}{\frac{-4}{x}dx}$

$=-4\lim_{a \rightarrow 0^-}(ln|a|-ln|-7|) -4\lim_{b \rightarrow 0^+}(ln|9|-ln|b|) \quad $ integral does not converge!

Comment: Haha, i see your point. This question is an online homework assignment for my Calculus students... There are a lot of bad questions like this!!! People who make these questions never actually take analysis classes it seems ahaha

Comment: Yeah, I saw later comments by others...